# How to assign a JSONObject value to a field in graphql schema file?

Tags: graphql-java, graphql-schema

I am working on an application with graphQL and spring boot framework. Here I am using GraphQL's Schema-first approach to write my schema details. In my scenario, I need to assign JSONObject and JSONArray as input to few of the fields in my Schema file. In graphQL schema file, we can not directly set JSONObject/JSONArray as data types. Can someone please guide me on how to handle JSONObject/JSONArray in graphQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own scalar type JSON:

```
scalar JSON

type Foo {
  field: JSON
}
```

Then implement a new java GraphQLScalarType bean:

```
@Component
public class JSONScalarType extends GraphQLScalarType {

  JSONScalarType() {
    super("JSON", "JSON value", new Coercing<Object,Object>() {
        ...
    });
  }   
}
```

Finally implement the scalar Coercing. You can find a tutorial on scalar types here https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v15/scalars/

Or, as in graphql a JSON is an object, you can have a look at how the graphql-java-extended-scalars implemented the Object and JSON scalars : https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/scalars/object/ObjectScalar.java

Another solution would be to use the graphql-java-extended-scalars library: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars

Comment: Thank you Allirion..! You saved my time, It works.!

Comment: @DingThree you're welcome! Could you let me know which solution you used (custom scalar or use the extended-scalar library)?

Comment: Hello AllirionX - I have created a custom scalar and mapped it with my schema file. And, it worked perfectly.! Thank you.!

Comment: Has someone got the complete implementation of the call, sharing will be helpful?